# target all not headings

Tags: html, css, selector

I'm trying to write a CSS selector to target all elements that are not headings (`h1`, `h2`, `h3`, ...)

I've googled "all not headings css" and "not headings css". Nothing relevant came up so I decided to ask here.

I've tried to do this:

```
body :not( h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 ) {
  /* yada yada yada */
}
```

I've noticed that this works:

```
body :not(h1), body :not(h2), body :not(h3) /* et cetera */ {
  /* yada yada yada */
}
```

But I'd rather not have to type all that and I'm afraid it will make my code hard to navigate. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @Daniel I guess I could do that! Do you mean put all the headings in a class?

Comment: I deleted my comment. Come to think of it, it didn't make sense. Your headings would need to have the class assigned.

Comment: @Daniel k. Paulie_D's answer below looks like the way to go, but I'll wait before accepting it to see if there are any more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain the `:not` selectors

```
body *:not(h1):not(h2):not(h3) /* et cetera */ {
 color:red
}
```

```css
body *:not(h1):not(h2):not(h3)
/* et cetera */

{
  color: red
}
```

```html
<p>Red Text</p>

<h1>Black H1</h1>

<h2>Black H2</h2>
```